# Rails validation: Which method is preferred

Tags: programming-practices, ruby-on-rails, validation

In Ruby on Rails there are two ways to validate, for instance, the `presence` of input fields. Say I want to make sure the user has filled out my fields called `value` and `name`. I could put in my model either:

```
validates_presence_of :value, :name

## Or

validates :value, presence: true
validates :name, presence: true
```

In this situation judging strictly by DRYness, method 1 looks better, but in the application I'm working on I have the following validation:

```
validates_presence_of :value, :name
validates_uniqueness_of :value
validates_numericality_of :value, :only_integer => true

## Which I can refactor to:

validates :value, presence: true, uniqueness: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
validates :name, presence: true
```

And in this case the second method looks better.

- Is there a generally preferred method, or is it case-by-case? (If it's case-by-case, wouldn't it be confusing for maintainers?)
- Is it safe to adopt one method for the entire application? (If so, which one should I adopt?)

Answer (score 5):

Maintainability trumps all. Unless you have a pressing reason not to, follow the conventions as they appear in the reference material.

In this case, the first Google hit is the documentation for validations at [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), which shows a strong preference to the `validates` form. The only counter example I could find was `validates_associated`, which makes sense as it does not actually validate the current object.

I would recommend picking one way to do it, as it facilitates visually scanning the code.

Personally, I prefer the flexibility of the `validates` version.